# Where found all the declarations of the System properties

Tags: java, properties, centos, system

I'm debugging a java code running on a Centos machine.

when I run System.getProperties() in a javacode I got a lot of properties where I dont know where they are declared ..

I searched in ~/.bash_profile and in ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile and I cant found them there !!

How can I know where these variables are declared ?

Comment: They aren't "declared" anywhere. The JVM populates that `Properties` object on startup. I don't believe you can influence them via a dotfile, but there may be vendor specific features that allow it.

Comment: I just found the variables in the my Jetty start.ini file .. as you said they are declared as JVM properties .... what I've understand the System.getProperties list the JVM variables ! right ?

Comment: It really depends on which properties you are talking about. [This page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) lists the ones that are always available. Anything beyond that is vendor specific.

Comment: Ok, I see :) thanks @SeanBright